# Why is not Yom Kippur is kept from the Mazikim

Tags: yom-kippur

It is written that Satan has no control on this day (Yom Kippur), so why, unlike the Seder Night, we say a regular Kriyat Shema on the bed? Moreover, in the Machzorim there are additional Psalms chapters that are supposed to prevent sins at night?

Comment: Because it's not a leil shimurim?

Comment: No satan means no mazikim?

Comment: We don't say the same Kriat Shema on Seder night? Maybe it's "on the bed" that I'm not understanding.